# need to share documents created in ios-air-app with itunes

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I created an adobe air based ios app, which creates a textfile ( a csv document to be precise ) I used:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(timestamp+".txt");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(the_string);
```

the file gets created and I can access it using a third party tool like iExplorer.
however in itunes I cannot get to this file.

is there some special thing I need to declare in the application descriptor?
thanks a lot for all infos and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is "yes" ;)

What i found out i need to do ist add 
    UIFileSharingEnabled

to the app-descriptor.xml and voilà: the documents appear in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply **NO**

I had the same issue on some projects.

1. iTunes has no idea what to do with a CSV :)
2. iTunes does actually not give the possibility to access the filesystem of the device itself
3. All files created belong to the sandbox of your app.
4. You cannot even use iCloud for this :(

My "workaround" was a webserver to which I simply uploaded the files.